# Angular NgFor iterate through x objects in array

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I want to iterate through the first four objects of an array. I want to use ngFor instead of selecting the first four objects like this:

```
{{ users[*]?.UserName }}
```

* being the 0-3

I want to use this:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"> 
{{user?.UserName}}
```

This works but displays all users in the array and I only need the first 4 (index 0-3). 
Is there a way to tell the ngFor something like: i<4?

Comment: You can splice the users based on index
```
<div *ngFor="let user of users.splice(0, index); let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"> 
{{user?.UserName}}</div>
```

Comment: splice does just remove the users in the array right?

Comment: yes, in that case you can use slice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pipe `slice:0:3` like below

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users | slice:0:3; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">

    {{user?.UserName}}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjgubx

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. use ngconainter and ng if for limiting the number of users to 4.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users; index as i" [attr.data-index]="i"> 
    <ng-container *ngIf="i<4">
       {{user?.UserName}}
    </ng-container>
</div>
```